# @spawn and @async behavior in the REPL

Tags: julia

I've read through the [documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/) for `@async` and `@spawn`, but this isn't shown:

```
function f1(j)
    for i=1:j
       println(i*j)
    end
end

function f2(j)
    for i=1:j
       @spawn println(i*j)
    end
end
```

When run the second value is always skipped with both `@async` and `@spawn`

```
julia> f1(5)
5
10
15
20
25

julia> f2(5)
5

julia>
15
20
25
```

It doesn't seem to have an impact on the output of the data into an array *(...or does it?)*, and doing `@sync f2(5)` reverts the behavior. Mostly just wondering why this happens and why the second value?

**Edit:**
It acts like this on two systems:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+4850
Commit c260ea9* (2015-05-15 15:14 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2415M CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+4888
Commit ca2ca31* (2015-05-18 15:20 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_LAPACK NO_LAPACKE DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Bulldozer)
  LAPACK: liblapack.so.3
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

Comment: That's not the behavior I get (I get ALL the numbers followed by the newlines) on linux. I'd say the output gap is most likely a question of how the terminal handles newlines on your system. Perhaps add versioninfo() so someone with the same system can reproduce it or try setting TERM to "dumb" to see if the behavior changes with less terminal support.

Comment: Okay, I added the `versioninfo()` output and I'll try setting it to "dumb" (wouldn't have thought it was my terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce the problem if I use the 0.4 nightly:

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.4.0-dev+5032 (2015-05-27 06:04 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit bae38c2* (0 days old master) 
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0



julia> function f2(j)
                  for i=1:j
                     @spawn println(i*j)
                  end
              end
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(5)
5

julia>
15
20
25
```

Version 0.3 tends to choose a different timing which does not have destructive competition for drawing to the terminal:

```
julia> f2(5)
510152025





julia>
```

(Here, each println worked out as a buffer print and a newline print interleaved with the other tasks.)

The reason 0.4 nightly's output looks like it is not complete is just the combination of how timing works out with how terminals handle newlines, moving to a dumb terminal allows the 10 to be seen:

```
$ TERM="dumb" ./julia-4
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.4.0-dev+5032 (2015-05-27 06:04 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit bae38c2* (0 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

WARNING: Terminal not fully functional
julia> function f2(j)
           for i=1:j
               @spawn println(i*j)
           end
       end
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(5)
5

julia> 10
15
20
25
```

In general, you can count on any processing you request via `@spawn` or `@async` to be carried out, you just can't count on how the competition for any shared resources works out. This case of a shared terminal is one example. Any shared data structure built by async/spawned processes could be built by the computations running in any order and interleaving their modifications, etc.

An example where the main task handles organizing the output of the other tasks could look like this:

```
function f3(j)
    x = Any[@spawn i*j for i=1:j]
    for i in x
       println(fetch(i))
    end
end
```

Naturally, this would only perform well enough to make up for the cost of moving the data around if the `i*j` were replaced with a function with high CPU usage and/or reasons to wait for I/O that were more significant than the bottleneck of writing to the single output file or TTY.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. None of this should impact the data outside of the terminal, e.g., writing that output (using `@spawn`) to a file? I've only been using the nightly builds. Wanting to make sure that's not a mistake.

Comment: @snd since the 0.3 behavior is valid (println is nonatomic) you can't really share writable files among tasks without using some form of synchronisation. For multitasking in general you have to look closely at what guarantees there are and either use sync primitives or make one task responsible for anything that needs a specific order. I'll add an example of making the main task responsible.

Comment: Thanks. Your example really helps my understanding/learning. "..you have to look closely at what guarantees there are.." thanks for this too. Didn't realize asking this question could potentially save me from some headaches in the future... since I haven't been looking at this very closely at all.